# How can I prevent automatic rounding of numbers in excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

A1=35.0

A2=3.00

A3=quotient(A1,A2)

A3 is currently returning 11.00. But the format for all cells is "number", with 2 decimal places explicitly set.

How do you format cell A3 to return the value 11.67? This problem is not isolated to this specific worksheet; it occurs in all my Excel files.

Answer (score 7):

The `QUOTIENT()` function is specifically designed to only return whole integers.  If you want the exact value, just use regular division.

In Cell A3 put this `=A1/A2` instead of the quotient function.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I make QUOTIENT(533.03;55) it returns 10 instead of 9.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro putting the formula `=QUOTIENT(533.03,55)` in a cell returns 9 for me, as expected.  If you are actually using references instead of explicit numbers, you might have a math error somewhere else causing it to return the unexpected value.  QUOTIENT always returns the whole number portion of a division.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I increase decimal to anything more than 1 numbers after comma it shows `9.6543` but when I set to round, it becomes 10 :S I used `ROUNDDOWN()`.